# Should I create a Joint table or add foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm busy designing a database for my app, I made the relationship between tables... and after, I realized that instead of using foreign key and place it in another table I can only use a new joint table that will contain primary key for each table.

Not sure if any one used to achieve it?

**Also Microsoft in its ASP.Net MVC template on this below picture created an additional table named **UsersInRoles** (Joint table) for Users and Roles instead of adding a foreign key in the many table.** 
[image]

*PS : I'm not referring to foreign key in terms of constraint but instead in design perspective (General Database design).*

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: Place foreign key in other table?!?

Comment: Are the relationships 1-to-many or many-to-many?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server for this project. but I also have upcoming projects which I'll be using MySQL. But Database design it's a general concept for all of them and not related to a specific.. from my understanding.

Comment: @GirlCode . . . You should use foreign keys with no intermediate table for a 1-n relationship; you should use the intermediate table when you have an m-n relationship.  You haven't specified anything about what you want to model, so your question is incomplete.

Comment: It's a 1 to 1 relationship. I use ASP.Net MVC - microsoft built-in tables (please see the above picture). In this relationship, one user can only have one role (like Windows OS (7, 10) in which the user is either Standard or Admin) and cannot be both.  Weird that Microsoft created a additional table to put primary key from both table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what DBMS you're using, but personally I would prefer using foreign keys because many DBMS and other related products has built in support related to foreign keys. Also, a joint/mapping table will add redundancy of data, compared to using foreign keys.

Comment: So Why Microsoft in the above picture used joint table? (ASP.Net MVC template application)